# what is the lava rising command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to know what is the command to make lava rise in my world. I don't want to use any mods, since last time I tried using a mod, I got a virus. I've tried a bunch of Youtube tutorials, but nothing works. If anyone has a tutorial or knows how to do it, please share!

Comment: Voting closing because this is a looking for a pre-made solution. Also a "rising lava" isn't a feature of Minecraft Java/Bedrock. It needs to be implemented using commands and this essentially is a "pls code for me, idk how".